# Magento 2.3 EE: Make reward points to not apply automatically

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, quote, sales, reward-points

In Magento 2.3 EE, if a customer has reward points balance it is automatically applied to cart when the cart page is loaded and customer goes to the checkout process.

I want to remove this functionality and provide customers the choice to use reward points in the checkout process. For this I have made the "Use reward points" section visible on the checkout page. Now I only need to stop the reward points getting applied automatically to quote.

I tried removing the observers one by one but cannot find where exactly the reward points are applied to quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the module is using an extension attribute in quote. The value in this extension attribute is used as a condition to recollect totals.

I created an observer on cart load and set the extension attribute to false.

Used the event `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\RewardsOverride\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

class CartLoad implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
        $quote->setUseRewardPoints(false)->save();
    }
}
```